# Verificar dependência/ligação entre arquivos PHP

Tags: php, dependências

Tenho uma aplicação legado onde trabalho e sei que tem muito lixo no código. Preciso eliminar esses lixos e deixar apenas arquivos que realmente estão em uso.

Alguém conhece alguma ferramenta ou técnica que possam ajudar nisto? (verificar se há ligação entre arquivos?

Comment: Você pode usar recursividade para vasculhar todos os diretórios e ir salvando o nome dos arquivos dependentes em uso.

Comment: @AndreiCoelho e se o projeto usa autoload ou algum arquivo é incluído dinamicamente? `include($filepath)`.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss tem rasão! XD